# How i may select and sort character in HTML Tag using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some blocker. How can i select character and sort this inside a tag like `<p>`-tag in jQuery OR Vanilla JS?

```js
function alphabet(str){
    var x = str.split(" ");
    return x.sort().join(" ");
}
alert(alphabet("foo bar moo"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>foo bar moo</p>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6bL9uay6/)

Answer (score 2):

Set the `.textContent` of `<p>` element to result of `alphabet()` call

```
var p = document.querySelector("p"); 
p.textContent = alphabet(p.textContent.trim());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)** to get and set an element content.

Your code should look like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].textContent = alphabet(document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].textContent);
```

**Demo:**

```js
function alphabet(str) {
  var x = str.split(" ");
  return x.sort().join(" ");
}
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].textContent = alphabet(document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].textContent);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  foo bar moo
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. **get** DOM element
   JS: `var domElement = [depends on element and client];`
   https://plainjs.com/javascript/selecting/
   jQuery: `var $element = $('selector');`
   http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
2. **get** elements text
   JS: `var sText = domElement.innerText;`
   jQuery: `var sText = $element.text();`
3. **set** elements text
   JS: `domElement.innerText = sText;`
   jQuery: `$element.text( sText );`
   in your case: `sText = alphabet( sText );`

---

## jQuery

```
jQuery('p').text( alphabet( jQuery('p').text() ) );
jQuery('selector').text( alphabet( jQuery('selector').text() ) ); // generic
```

```js
function alphabet(str) {
    var x = str.split(" ");
    return x.sort().join(" ");
}

var $p = jQuery('p');
$p.text( alphabet( $p.text() ) );
alert(alphabet("foo bar moo"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>foo bar moo</p>
```

## JavaScript

```
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText = alphabet(
    document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText
);
domElement.innerText = alphabet( domElement.innerText ); // generic
```

```js
function alphabet(str) {
    var x = str.split(" ");
    return x.sort().join(" ");
}
var domP = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
domP.innerText = alphabet( domP.innerText );
alert(alphabet("foo bar moo"));
```

```html
<p>foo bar moo</p>
```

### jQuery | Plugin

If you want to reuse your "alphabet" function a lot you could deploy it as chainable jQuery plugin for convenience and use it straight forward.

```
jQuery('p').alphabet();
jQuery('selector').alphabet(); // generic
```

```js
(function($){
    $.fn.alphabet = function() {
        return this.each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.text(
                $.trim( $this.text() ).split(" ").sort().join(" ")
            )
        })
    }
})(jQuery)

jQuery('p')
    .css('color', 'red')
    .not(':first')
    .alphabet() /* chaining rocks */
    .css('color', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>foo bar moo</p>
<p>foo bar moo</p>
<p>foo bar moo</p>
```

### JavaScript | Node.prototype.alphabet

```
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].alphabet();
domElement.alphabet(); // generic
```

```js
if (!Node.prototype.alphabet) {
    Node.prototype.alphabet = function () {
         this.innerText = this.innerText
            .replace(/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g, '')
            .split(" ").sort().join(" ");
         return this; // make it chainable
    };
}

document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0]
  .alphabet() /* chaining rocks */
  .style.color = 'green';
```

```html
<p>foo bar moo</p>
```

### JavaScript | String.prototype.alphabet

```
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText.alphabet();
domElement.innerText = domElement.innerText.alphabet(); // generic
```

```js
if (!String.prototype.alphabet) {
    String.prototype.alphabet = function () {
         return this
            .replace(/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g, '')
            .split(" ").sort().join(" ");
    };
}

var domP = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
domP.innerText = domP.innerText.alphabet();
```

```html
<p>foo bar moo</p>
```

---

#### Notes

- `innerText` has very broad [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=innerText).
- `textContent` is not [supportet in](http://caniuse.com/#search=textContent) IE < 9.
- As others mentioned it could be reasonable to trim your text. IMHO this would be in scope of your function "alphabet".
  JS: `function alphabet(s){ return s.trim().split(" ").sort().join(" "); }`
  jQuery: `function alphabet(s){ return jQuery.trim(s).split(" ").sort().join(" "); }`
  *JS native trim function ([String.prototype.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)) is not [supportet in](http://caniuse.com/#search=trim) IE < 9.* So if you already use jQuery in a project I suggest to prefer jQuery.trim() instead. If not there is also a handy polyfill.

  ```
  if (!String.prototype.trim) {
      String.prototype.trim = function () {
          return this.replace(/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g, '');
      };
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

> You should Remove whitespace from both sides of a string:

```js
function alphabet(str){
var x = str.split(" ");
return x.sort().join(" ");
}
console.log(alphabet($("p").text().trim()));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
foo bar moo
</p>
```